# How to update current view in Highstock / Highcharts based on new Plotlines?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts

I have a graph, whereby users can add plotlines themselves by clicking a button. Often, those plotlines are added outside the current view of the graph, which means the user has to manually zoom out to search for the plotline they added. Is it possible for HighStock to dynamically change its current view based on added Plotlines?

Check out this example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ltgzwpo2/2/

If you click on the button, a plotline is added OUTSIDE of the current view, i.e. you need to zoom out to find the plotline. Is it possible for the chart to dynamically zoom out itself upon the adding of a plotline?

This is the code I use to add a plotline:

```
  $("#button").click(function() {
    chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({
      value: Date.UTC(2015, 10, 5),
      color: "green",
      width: 1,
      dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
      label: {
        text: "this appeared outside of the current view!",
        align: 'left',
        y: 5,
        x: 3,
        style: {
          fontSize: "12px"
        }
      },
      zIndex: 10
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [axis.setExtremes()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.setExtremes) to set the visible area.

```
var value = Date.UTC(2015, 10, 5);

chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({
  value: value,
  color: "green",
  width: 1,
  dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
  label: {
    text: "this appeared outside of the current view!",
    align: 'left',
    y: 5,
    x: 3,
    style: {
      fontSize: "12px"
    }
  },
  zIndex: 10
});

var range = 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 30;

chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(value - range, value + range)
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/cqwk84dz/